# Stuck with classic ASP form submission

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to classic asp. I have developed a simple asp form where I am doing a form submission to access database. I got a code to do a form validation on fields but the code works only when I you same asp code. When I change the form method to different asp file, validation doesn't work.

### Form.asp

```
....code
<%
    Dim send, txtengineer, txtcaseid, txtassetno, txtusername, txtgroup, txtLOB, txtmodel, txtsim, countError
    send = Request.Form("submit")
    txtengineer = Request.Form("engineer")
    txtcaseid = Request.Form("caseid")
    txtasset = Request.Form("asset")
    txtusername = Request.Form("username")
    txtgroup = Request.Form("group")
    txtLOB = Request.Form("lob")
    txtmodel = Request.Form("model")
    txtsim = Request.Form("sim")
    countError = 0
%>
<form method="post" action="form.asp">
....
<%
            if send <> "" AND txtcaseid = "" then
                Response.Write "<span class=""message""> << Enter Case no.</span>"
                countError = countError + 1
            end If
%>
```

### DB.asp

This is the code where I want to submit the collected field value. Which is working fine. I have forced to keep  wherein I am want to do

I want to validate first then submit the form afterwards. I know I am doing something stupid.

Need some guidance to fix the code blocks. 
Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What exactly isn't working in this code?

Comment: I would suggest that you validate each value first to ensure a something has been returned via your form/query string data, also. E.g. `send = CStr(Request.Form("submit"))` ... and `If IsNumeric(Request.Form("someFormData"))` Then...`

Comment: If you change the URL in your forms `action` attribute to something other then `form.asp` you will have to incorporate the validation logic in that new URL as well. Classic ASP is a server-side technology so the form has to be submitted *(to the page in the forms `action` attribute)* before the validation logic can be checked. If you want client-side validation you should be looking at using JavaScript to check your fields before the form is submitted to the server.

Comment: Apologies if my question was not clear. I think I got some hint from Lankymart response (which I was not aware). Basically I want to submit a form to the database but before that perform a form validation (ex: ensure that the user name field is not empty etc - avoid null value entries).

Comment: Can you help me with any sample code (Java script or VBScript) to perform client side form validation? I just want to avoid null values.

Comment: To help with that @Jas we would need to see some of your client side code such as the HTML that defines your inputs for the value that becomes `txtcaseid` for example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with having the form submit to a different page is, what do you do if there are errors? Tell the user to hit their "back" button? For that reason alone, I'd recommend putting the DB code in the same page as the form. If you can't do that, you need to move your server-side validation to the DB page. The client-side validation would still be on the form page. (Note that if you're only going to do one type of validation, it must be server-side.)

If you do everything in one page, the basic structure would look like this:

```vbs
<html><head>[etc.]
<%
Const errstr = "<span class='err'>*</span>"
Dim txtengineer, txtcaseid '[etc.]
Dim counterror(8) '- 8 = number of fields
counterror(0) = 0
If Request.Form <> "" Then
    txtengineer = Request.Form("engineer")
    'etc. with other fields
    Validate
    If counterror(0) = 0 Then
        SavetoDB
        Response.Redirect "Success.asp"
    End If
End If
Sub Validate()
    If txtengineer = "" Then
      counterror(1) = 1
      counterror(0) = counterror(0) + 1
    Else
      'do whatever other cleanup/validation you need
    End If
    'etc. for other fields
End Sub
Sub SavetoDB()
 'code to write stuff to database goes here
End Sub
%>
<script>
function validate(){
//client-side validation goes here
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%
If counterror(0) > 0 Then
    Response.Write "<p>Please fill out the required fields (*) below.</p>"
End If
%>
<form method="post" action="form.asp">
<p>Engineer: <input type="text" name="engineer" value="<%=txtengineer%>" size="30" maxlength="50">
   <%If counterror(1) = 1 Then Response.Write errstr%>
</p>
[etc. with other fields]
<p><input type="submit" name="Btn" value="Submit" onclick="validate();"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Jas: if my answer was helpful to you, you can mark it as "accepted" - that'll tell the system that this question has been answered satisfactorily.